# How to refresh table data when in edit mode in latest versions of SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server Management Studio, it is possible to open a table and see its contents, this is done by:

- right clicking on the table
- choosing *Edit first N rows* (where N is a parameter that defaults to 200)

In SQL Server 2008 R2 there was a button (I think a button with a exclamation mark icon if I remember correctly) that caused a refresh of the data on being clicked. This is very convenient in testing and development scenarios.

With the latest versions of SQL Server Management Studio (2016 at least), I cannot find that button anymore and so to refresh data I need to close the table and again select "edit first N rows" from the context menu.

Does anyone know how to refresh the data?

To express myself better:

this is the toolbar in ssms 2008R2 (I found this on a test server still at 2008R2):

[image: 2008r2 Toolbar]

The "!" icon is the one I am not finding in ssms2016:

[image: 2016 Toolbar]

Comment: Do you mean the "Execute" button or the F5 key..?

Comment: @Larnu not exactly. Execute/F5 works with a query, but when a table is opened that i not available, there was another button (That may be has been on purpose removed by Microsoft). That one I am looking for

Comment: What do you mean *"When the table is opened that i not available"*? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Those table views have underlying SQL commands that execute to display the results. Invoking the "execute SQL" command (Ctrl-R) is equivalent to refreshing the view. F5 binds (globally, without further context like the Query Editor) to View -> Refresh, which still exists as a command, but has no effect in the data grid editor anymore.

Comment: Ctrl - R as Andrea replied is my solution F5 <> Ctrl- R at least in this context

Comment: The `!` was the Execute button... http://www.kodyaz.com/images/articles/SQL2008-SSMS/SSMS-2008-Object-Explorer-Details-Windows-F7.JPG

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default shortcut should be <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

You can check in Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard :

[image]

Comment: YEs CTRL - R does the job. Relative button is simply hidden by default.

Comment: @LaBracca: it's displayed by default for me. The icon is a table with a "play" symbol next to it, it's located on the Query Designer toolbar. Maybe that one's not displayed by default.

Comment: yes now i found it. i installed so many ssms versions on my pc and may be the defaults get messed up.

Answer (score 3):

Icon is different in Management studio 2016:

[image]